# Handling wpf control events in the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling

Is there an alternative to Attached Command Behaviour for handling events like DataGrid's MouseDoubleClick event, or TextBox's LostFocus event in the ViewModel ?

e.g.,   View::

```
    <Window ........
            DataContext=".......">


        <TextBox LostFocus="{Binding Command1}" />

        <! -- or -->

        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid MouseDoubleClick="{Binding Command2}".../>

    </Window>
```

ViewModel::

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public ICommand Command1
   {
      .......
   }


   public ICommand Command2
   {
      .......
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use attached command behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a BindEvent class which I use in the view to bind an event to a method in the datacontext. I use it like this:

```
public MyView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(BindEvent.Create("ControlLoaded"));
}
```

I can add the source here later if you are interested.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to achieve this without any code behind. Guess I'd have to go with ACBs after all. But thanks for replying.